# Problem on understand the ros2_control demo code

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I try to understand the ros2_control on differential drive hardware interface from demo  code.
I already send cmd_val for move the robot , and it move in rviz2.
My problem is I find the log code for example like below, but none of the log show in terminal, there any setup that I need to configure to make the log show into the terminal?  I have notice by change the code in ros2_control_demo_hardware/src/diffbot_system.cpp:*- comment the code in read and write function* did not give any effect to it.....I still can control the robot model in rviz2 by using cmd_val....  please advice

```
RCLCPP_INFO(
      rclcpp::get_logger("DiffBotSystemHardware"),
      "Got position state %.5f and velocity state %.5f for '%s'!", hw_positions_[i],
      hw_velocities_[i], info_.joints[i].name.c_str());
```

The output in terminal is show below. Any info please advice.

```
shahrol@cloud001:~/ros2control_ws$ ros2 launch ros2_control_demo_bringup diffbot_system.launch.py 
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/shahrol/.ros/log/2021-08-22-16-21-04-744139-cloud001-134924
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-1]: process started with pid [134928]
[INFO] [ros2_control_node-2]: process started with pid [134930]
[INFO] [spawner.py-3]: process started with pid [134932]
[INFO] [spawner.py-4]: process started with pid [134934]
[robot_state_publisher-1] Parsing robot urdf xml string.
[robot_state_publisher-1] The root link base_link has an inertia specified in the URDF, but KDL does not support a root link with an inertia.  As a workaround, you can add an extra dummy link to your URDF.
[robot_state_publisher-1] Link caster_frontal_wheel had 0 children
[robot_state_publisher-1] Link caster_rear_wheel had 0 children
[robot_state_publisher-1] Link left_wheel had 0 children
[robot_state_publisher-1] Link right_wheel had 0 children
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1629620465.260133412] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1629620465.260239956] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment caster_frontal_wheel
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1629620465.260257605] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment caster_rear_wheel
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1629620465.260270296] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment left_wheel
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1629620465.260287220] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment right_wheel
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO] [1629620465.284592757] [controller_manager]: update rate is 100 Hz
[spawner.py-4] [INFO] [1629620465.535399234] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for /controller_manager services
[spawner.py-3] [INFO] [1629620465.557948856] [spawner_diffbot_base_controller]: Waiting for /controller_manager services
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO] [1629620465.742730985] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'
[spawner.py-4] [INFO] [1629620465.760737880] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Loaded joint_state_broadcaster
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO] [1629620465.762902101] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO] [1629620465.766650485] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'diffbot_base_controller'
[spawner.py-3] [INFO] [1629620465.780861909] [spawner_diffbot_base_controller]: Loaded diffbot_base_controller
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO] [1629620465.800242009] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'diffbot_base_controller'
[spawner.py-4] [INFO] [1629620465.801521326] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Configured and started joint_state_broadcaster
[spawner.py-3] [INFO] [1629620465.821667248] [spawner_diffbot_base_controller]: Configured and started diffbot_base_controller
[INFO] [spawner.py-4]: process has finished cleanly [pid 134934]
[INFO] [spawner.py-3]: process has finished cleanly [pid 134932]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/384882/problem-on-understand-the-ros2_control-demo-code/) by [shahrol.baharom](https://answers.ros.org/users/76634/shahrol.baharom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2021-08-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Darkproduct](https://answers.ros.org/users/52476/darkproduct/) on 2021-08-24**:
What exactly do you want to archive? Do you use Gazebo or do you run the code on a real robot?

**Comment by [shahrol.baharom](https://answers.ros.org/users/76634/shahrol.baharom/) on 2021-08-24**:
Hi, I would like to run the code on real robot..... hope you can help me in the process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This the solution of my problem, what you need to make the hardware interface work is by change the diffbot_system.urdf.xacro. Change it to true as show below.

<xacro:arg name="use_fake_hardware" default="false" />

---

Originally posted by [shahrol.baharom](https://answers.ros.org/users/76634/shahrol.baharom/) with karma: 76 on 2021-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> My problem is I find the log code for
> example like below, but none of the
> log show in terminal, there any setup
> that I need to configure to make the
> log show into the terminal?

This is probably due to not having this `output={"stdout": "screen","stderr": "screen",},` (I think the short version is `output="both"`) in your launch file, for all nodes you want to have in the terminal output.

Example:

```
Node(
    package="controller_manager",
    executable="ros2_control_node",
    parameters=[robot_description, controller_config_path],
    output={
        "stdout": "screen",
        "stderr": "screen",
    },
    condition=UnlessCondition(use_sim),
),
```

> I have notice by change the code in
> ros2_control_demo_hardware/src/diffbot_system.cpp:-
> comment the code in read and write
> function did not give any effect to
> it.....

This is either, because you didn't see the output, because of the problem above, or you maybe didn't compile? I don't really know.

What exactly do you mean by "I can control the robot in rviz?"
Do the wheel joints move in rviz and not on the real robot?

---

Originally posted by [Darkproduct](https://answers.ros.org/users/52476/darkproduct/) with karma: 100 on 2021-08-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shahrol.baharom](https://answers.ros.org/users/76634/shahrol.baharom/) on 2021-08-26**:
currently I have a  robot but it not complete, It just a piece of motor, motor driver, motor encoder and Arduino mega, all already mount on a frame.
I already write the firmware for Arduino mega for receive a serial data but with my own data format. Now I in process to write a serial driver for hardware interface. So I need to know what data need to send via serial.
I know ros2_control will get the linear and angular speed from cmd_val so I want to see how I can pack this info and send it via serial also how I can receive speed info from my robot.